# npm run watch no funciona mix watch

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-8

Bueno estoy practicando para crear un crud con laravel y tailwindcss, eh intentado varias cosas para solucionarlo, y creo que tiene que ver con npm o tal vez algo me falta con el webpack,me resultan los fallos, al dar php artisan serve me trae estos errores, entonces creo que hay algo que paso por alto, del webpack o de mix watch algo que no se ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intentando antes creo que se debe solucionar el problema con este comando pero desconozco que hacer
**npm run watch && npm run dev**

```
watch
mix watch
"mix" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

**npm run watch-poll**

```
 mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000 
"mix" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Comment: Primero tienes que instalar las dependencias `npm i` , luego corres `npm run dev`

Comment: no es el caso, es una solucion basica que no me ha servido, porque al parecer es problema de laravel mix

Comment: Cuál es el problema que mencionas de laravel-mix? Lo instalaste y aún así no funciona? Que versión estás usando? Como es el contenido de tus archivos package.json y webpack.mix.js? En el mensaje de error ya te está preguntando "Did you forget to run `npm install && npm run dev`?".

Comment: edito la publicación mas abajo, npm install y npm run dev es lo que sugiere y como comento no es la solución

Comment: Publica tu solución así le sirve a otros con el mismo problema. A propósito... ¿qué es esto `"tailwindcss": "npm:undefined@*"`?

Comment: eso hace parte de la instalacion de tailwindcss, he encontrado la solucion a que run watch funcione, decidi desistalar la dependencia de laravel-mix, e instalarla de nuevo ya que en un proyecto pasado me pasaba lo mismo pero basto con realizar "ncu -u" y lanzar "npm install && npm run watch", al parecer el tailwindcss tiene algun problema con versiones, ya que al lanzar el comando que sugiere el video se instala una version 5.0 cuando ya estamos en la 6.0, de momento esta corriendo el watch

Comment: Genial. En realidad para laravel, todo lo que es js y css devería estar en devDependencies pues no son dependencias para un entorno de producción. De todas maneras no afecta en nada que se haya pasado a dependencies en este caso, seguramente corriste el comando `npm install laravel-mix --save` en vez de `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev`.

Comment: es raro porque desinstalandolo de forma normal, corri npm i laravel-mix y por defecto lo lleva a dependencies, pero aun asi no comprendo mucho la diferencia entre ellas aun, pero ya se ha ido el `"tailwindcss": "npm:undefined@*"`

Answer (score 3):

**hay 2 casos para una solución**

**caso 1** en el package.json hay una version de laravel-mix antigua, para lo que se desea aplicando estaba en la devdependencies

```
ncu (para revisar) ncu -u (para actualizar)
```

seguido corremos

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

luego si sale error o mix no se reconoce en el caso con tailwindcss aplique

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

si persiste algun fallo, lo que hice fue forzar la instalacion de tailwindcss

```
npm install tailwindcss --force
```

**caso 2** si sale errores con la versión lo que hice fue desinstalar el laravel mix y reinstalarlo

```
npm uninstall laravel-mix  o npm remove laravel-mix
```

luego

```
npm i laravel-mix
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema, pero antes que nada explico que es el mix de laravel, Mix hace que sea muy fácil compilar y minimizar los archivos CSS y JavaScript de su aplicación. A través del encadenamiento de métodos simples, puede definir con fluidez su canalización de activos.

Teniendo en cuenta que es el mix ahora explico la instrucción que me ayudo a relsolver el problema.

**npm install resolve-url-loader --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps**

Esta instriccion resuelve el error generado por las rutas de los archivos dependientes al mix, cuando usa rutas totalmente relativas en url()declaraciones, Webpack espera encontrar esos activos junto al archivo raíz SCSS, independientemente de dónde especifique el archivo url(). En la siguiente imagen se muestra una ramificación del archivo del cual no se pudo acceder, causa principal del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora explico las banderas de la instrucción:

Priema bandera (--save-dev):
Se utiliza para guardar el paquete para fines de desarrollo. Ejemplo: pruebas unitarias, minificación.

Segunda bandeta (--legacy-peer-deps):
Una forma de pensar en esta bandera es que no está haciendo algo nuevo; más bien le dice a NPM que no haga algo nuevo simplemente que restaure el comportamiento de instalación, ya que NPM v7 ahora instala peerDependencies de forma predeterminada.

luego:

**npm run dev**

y listo.

Espero les sirva, saludos desde México ✌.

Comment: ¿Podrias explicar el porque eso soluciona el problema?  No dudo que lo haga pero no lo entiendo, me falta algo de explicación. Léete [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), gracias por tu aporte de todos modos.

Comment: Le hice una edición a mi respuesta espero les sirva y que me haya podido explicar mejor, muchas gracias por el comentario y el elnace.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora sí que es una buena respuesta (antes estaba considerada de "baja calidad" por baremos de SO).  Muchas gracias por tu aporte y tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes actualizar a la última versión de Laravel Mix.

Usa este comando:

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas, te damos la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. No te olvides de completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre  el sitio (y así ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.